# AndroidCompatibility

Tags: android, compatibility

I am creating an app in which I want to change the view of my app depending on the Android version.

In my view,I want to show three tabs:

```
 Simple tab - lower API 10
 Action Bar tab 11 - API 14
 View Pager - above API 14.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can also use support package to support the new tech on old API as well: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT), the SDK level (integer) the phone API level is available in:

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

Code example:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion > 14) {
   // do something for View Pager
}
else if (currentapiVersion >= 11 && currentapiVersion <= 14) {
   // do something for Action Bar tab
}
else { 
   // do something Simple tab 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For froyo or lower:`if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9)`

For Honeycomb or Lower :`if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 12)`

all other use else :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Action Bar Sherlock. It act according to the version. Go through this [link here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

It helps you

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean froyoOrNewer() {
    // SDK_INT is introduced in 1.6 (API Level 4) so code referencing that would fail
    // Also we can't use SDK_INT since some modified ROMs play around with this value, RELEASE is most versatile variable
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("1.") ||
        android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("2.0") ||
        android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("2.1"))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```